# Serial Connection Not Working on Modified Router

Tags: pcb, hardware, network, header

I have a Sagem F@ST 2504 router. Following the advice from OpenWRT wiki (http://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/sagem/fast2404) I managed to solder the header pins in the correct place. I've attached pics below. My soldering isn't the best, but I'm working with a gas iron that I'm not too comfortable with.

[image]

[image]

The pins from right to left are:

```
...................o Pwr
...................o Rx
...................o Tx 
...................o Gnd
```

I am using this USB to serial cable: http://www.adafruit.com/product/954

I am using Minicom 2.2 on the Mac to connect to the router via serial.

These are the steps I follow:

1. Connect cable to header pins. Pwr -> Pwr, Rx -> Tx, Tx -> Rx, Gnd -> Gnd.
2. Open terminal on mac and type: `/opt/minicom/2.2/bin/minicom -s`
3. In `Minicom` I've tried various baud rates. I use, but the recommendation is  `9600 8N1`
4. Minicom initializes the modem, but when I press CTRL + A `mincom` says Offline. Nothing is displayed in the terminal.

Note that when testing I do not plug the router into the mains. I use the 3.3v header. I've tried with power though, which didn't solve my problem.

I'm at a bit of a loose end here. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong or what I'm missing?

Comment: Minicom will always say offline unless you're using a real modem when it will change to online when you are actively connected to a remote computer.  Online/Offline is keyed on the Carrier Detect signal, which you don't have in a small USB dongle like that.

Comment: Ok I see. But I'm still not able to see anything in the terminal. When I connect my Rasberry Pi via the header pins I can get a shell on the Pi. Not able to get anything on the router.

Comment: Often you will only get a brief bit on the terminal when you power on, and you won't get anything else unless you press a key to enter terminal mode at the right time.  Disconnect the +3.3 pin and just use external power. Power cycle while connected and see what you get.

Comment: @Majenko post as answer. That worked. Slight problem is the session will freeze. I'm not sure if that's a Mac terminal issue because it only freezes when I scroll up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, the Online / Offline indicator is a bit of a misnomer.  The online state is tied to the Carrier Detect (CD) line being asserted, and that is usually done when a real modem has negotiated a proper connection to a remote modem.  You don't have a CD line on a little USB dongle like that, so you can completely ignore the Offline status.

Secondly, it's quite common for the console to not give any output except during the first few moments of booting. If it doesn't get a signal (pressing a key at the right time) it will assume there is no console connected, and not bother wasting time outputting data to something that's not there.

By disconnecting the +3.3V pin and powering the board externally it will give you the ability to power-cycle the board.  By being connected at the time you power cycle the board you should get an initial boot message including something along the lines of *"Press any key for console mode"* or similar.  Pressing a key (or the right key if one is specified) should drop you into console mode, at which point you should be able to see the output you'd expect.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. It worked once, I think I caught the power cycle at the right time by accident.